# SQL How to get Account ids that had a purchase gap of 3 months

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table. I need to query `ACCOUNT_ID` where the `ACCOUNT_ID` has had at least a 3 month gap.

[image]

For example, `ACCOUNT_ID` 123 has the following. They have a gap of more than 3 months. How can I get this id?

[image]

I'm honestly super stuck here and have no idea what to do.

```
WITH LAST_PURCHASED AS (
SELECT
    lp."ACCOUNT_ID",
    MAX(lp."PO_DATE") AS "LAST_PUR_DATE",
    SUM(lp."QTY") AS "TTL_QTY"
FROM A
    AS lp
GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM A 
    INNER JOIN LAST_PURCHASED lp ON (A."ACCOUNT_ID" = lp."ACCOUNT_ID")
WHERE
    lp."LAST_PURCHASED" >= DATEADD(MONTH,-3,A."PO_DATE")
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windows function as follows:

```
select t.* from
(select t.*, max(diff) over  (partition by t."ACCOUNT_ID") as max_diff from
(select t.*,
       datediff(t."PO_DATE", lead(t."PO_DATE") 
                               over (partition by t."ACCOUNT_ID" 
                                     order by t."PO_DATE") ) as diff
  from A t) t ) t
where max_diff >= 3
```

Comment: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. I'm using Snowflake. @Popeye

Comment: you're a genius!!! How the heck did you even come up with this query....

Comment: I just checked with if any continuous PO_DATE ha difference of the 3 month? If yes, then fetch all the data of that account.

Comment: I knew I had to use Exists but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you again tho I honestly can't thank you enough.